# Django , how to remember that a user has logged in?

Tags: python, django, authentication

```
@csrf_protect
def loginn(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("login/login.html",c)

@csrf_protect
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return render_to_response('login/loggedin.html',RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/invalid')

def loggedin(request):
    return render_to_response('login/loggedin.html',
                                 {'full_name' : request.user.username})

def invalid_login(request):
    return render_to_response('login/invalid_login.html')

def logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return render_to_response('login/logout.html')
```

Here is what I have in my views.py . It's working , checking password , user , etc . 
But I don't know how to remember that a user has logged in.

I want to show logged/not logged users different Menus. 
Tried it like that in my `templates`:

```
{% block Menu %}
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
  <li>  <a href="/posts/login">Login</a> </li>
  <li>  <a href="/posts/register/">Register</a></li>
{% endif %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="/posts">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="/posts/logout">logout</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But it works only once and only with `render_to_response` + `RequestContent`
All other times I have first option. (Login , Register)

So how can I remember that a user has logged in?

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Yes, you need RequestContext as it automatically passes the `user` object to the template. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: @DanielRoseman that , when I go back to Main page , after logging in , it doesn't work and I again have (Login , Register) option (but I'm already logged in) instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Daniel Roseman's comment...

If you want to use render_to_response and have access to the current request objects in your templates, you'll need to pass along RequestContext as well.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
    my_data_dictionary,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You may want to take a look at using render instead though as it already includes RequestContext for you.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: Correct until the last point. `user` is supplied by the automatically-included `auth` context processor, but `request` is *not*: you'd need to add `django.core.context_processors.request` to access it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) However, maybe there is another way to remember that user is logged in and use it in template? Something with sessions, cookis , etc?